# How to call member methods of all subclasses of a trait?

Tags: scala, reflection

I've managed to list all subclasses of a given trait using knownDirectSubclasses() with scala-reflect. I'm not sure how to convert it to an instance of the object.

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{universe => ru}

sealed trait Parent extends Product {
  def toPrint: String = {
    getClass.getSimpleName() + "!!!"
  }
}

object UmbrellaObj {
  case object Child1 extends Parent {}
  case object Child2 extends Parent {}
  implicit def toString(f: Parent): String = f.toPrint
}
val tpe = ru.typeOf[Parent]
val clazz = tpe.typeSymbol.asClass
println(UmbrellaObj.Child1.toString)
clazz.knownDirectSubclasses.foreach(x => {
  println(x.toString)
})
```

In the above example, instead of x.toString(), I want to call member methods of the Child objects.

Comment: Reflection in Scala is a means of last resort. There is usually a better way to achieve whatever it is you need to do. You may want to give some context what this is about.

Comment: As for the question at hand: You can only create instances of a class by calling a constructor. What kind of parameters you need for that depends entirely on the class in question. In addition, some of those classes may be abstract, then you cannot make (direct) instances at all.

Comment: Consider using some library like Enumeratum: https://github.com/lloydmeta/enumeratum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your subclasses are `object`s, then you can retrieve the instances like this:

```
// objects are 'module classes'
val modules = clazz.knownDirectSubclasses
  .filter(_.isModuleClass).map(_.asClass.module.asModule)
val mirror = ru.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val instances: Set[Parent] = modules.map(mirror.reflectModule)
  .map(_.instance.asInstanceOf[Parent])
```